# Can't append XML nodes using jquery parseXML , but can append font

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xmlnode

**Jquery :**

```
    $.get("config.xml",function(xml){
        $(xml).find("config").find("images").append("<image><url>../demo/Headline/2012/12/20/0/0/A/Content/8/Web201212_P8_medium.jpg</url><name></name><redirect>none</redirect></image>");

    alert ($(xml).find("config").find("images").text());
    });
```

**XML:**

```
<config>
    <images>
        <central>1</central>
        <random>false</random>
        <width>199</width>
        <height>237</height>
        <image>
            <url>../demo/Headline/2012/12/20/0/0/A/Content/1/Web201212_P1_medium.jpg</url>
            <name></name>
            <redirect>none</redirect>
        </image>
        <image>
            <url>../demo/Headline/2012/12/20/0/0/A/Content/2/Web201212_P2_medium.jpg</url>
            <name></name>
            <redirect>none</redirect>
        </image>
        <image>
            <url>../demo/Headline/2012/12/20/0/0/A/Content/3/Web201212_P3_medium.jpg</url>
            <name></name>
            <redirect>none</redirect>
        </image>
        <image>
            <url>../demo/Headline/2012/12/20/0/0/A/Content/4/Web201212_P4_medium.jpg</url>
            <name></name>
            <redirect>none</redirect>
        </image>
        <image>
            <url>../demo/Headline/2012/12/20/0/0/A/Content/5/Web201212_P5_medium.jpg</url>
            <name></name>
            <redirect>none</redirect>
        </image>
        <image>
            <url>../demo/Headline/2012/12/20/0/0/A/Content/6/Web201212_P6_medium.jpg</url>
            <name></name>
            <redirect>none</redirect>
        </image>
        <image>
            <url>../demo/Headline/2012/12/20/0/0/A/Content/7/Web201212_P7_medium.jpg</url>
            <name></name>
            <redirect>none</redirect>
        </image>
    </images>
```

In the example above , I am able to append a string eg. 'abcdefg' to the xml  node. However, when I use html tag eg.  just like the example one, I can not append anything? How to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [$.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to parse the xml and then apply selector and append.

```
$.parseXML(xml).find("config").find("images").append("<image><url>../demo/Headline/2012/12/20/0/0/A/Content/8/Web201212_P8_medium.jpg</url><name></name><redirect>none</redirect></image>");
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (j,s){return new b.fn.init(j,s)} has no method 'parseXML' ?

Answer (score 0):

try to replace `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;` in your html first

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.get("config.xml",function(xml){
    $(xml).find("images").append("<image<url>../demo/Headline/2012/12/20/0/0/A/Content/8/Web201212_P8_medium.jpg</url><name></name><redirect>none</redirect></image>");

    alert ($(xml).find("images").text());
    });
```

Try This